# Big O for nested constant for loop

Tags: c++

Is this loop 0(1) ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      std::cout << i << j << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no variable sized input nor anything variable, thus yes it has constant complexity

Comment: possible reason for downvote (it wasnt me): The question demonstrates, that you didnt do any research on the topic

Answer (score 2):

Both 10 and 4 are constant, so yes, the time complexity is constant.

Answer (score 2):

**Not exactly**, it's not **0(1)**, it is **O(1)**.